# How to get a count from a Field in another Table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, left-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.tags, t.privacy, t.about, t.views, t.registered, t.updated, i.image_id
                FROM x_trybes t
                LEFT JOIN x_trybe_images i
                ON t.id = i.trybe_id
```

In addition to this query I have a table called:

x_trybes_likes, which has the following structure

id | trybe_id | profile_id

id being the primary key
trybe id being the relationship between this table and the x_trybes & x_trybe_images table
and the profile id, which relates to the users who have liked an x_trybe.

How can I append my query to faciliate a count, for e.g 4 people have liked the biology trybe. I.e. 4 rows in the x_trybes_likes table? Can anyone offer a solution?

I've tried this but it returns the top row for some reason :\ :

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.tags, t.privacy, t.about, t.views, t.registered, t.updated, i.image_id, COUNT(l.trybe_id) AS likes
                FROM x_trybes t
                LEFT JOIN x_trybe_images i
                ON t.id = i.trybe_id
                LEFT JOIN x_trybes_likes l
                ON t.id = l.trybe_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY`.

Give this a go:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.name, 
       t.tags, 
       t.privacy, 
       t.about, 
       t.views, 
       t.registered, 
       t.updated, 
       i.image_id, 
       COUNT(distinct l.id) AS likes
                FROM x_trybes t
                LEFT JOIN x_trybe_images i
                ON t.id = i.trybe_id
                LEFT JOIN x_trybes_likes l
                ON t.id = l.trybe_id
group by t.id, 
         t.name, 
         t.tags, 
         t.privacy, 
         t.about, 
         t.views, 
         t.registered, 
         t.updated, 
         i.image_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom! I need to look into this, not dabbed with Group By before, is that the reason it wasn't working? I'll accept the answer when I can

Comment: No worries. Here is some more info on `COUNT` (it has some info on `GROUP BY` too) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count. Good luck!